# Python - Print list of CSV strings in aligned columns

Tags: python, list, csv, format, stdout

I have written a fragment of code that is fully compatible with both `Python 2` and `Python 3`. The fragment that I wrote **parses data** and it builds the **output as a list of CSV strings**.

The script provides an **option** to:

- write the data to a `CSV file`, or
- display it to the `stdout`.

While I could easily iterate through the list and replace `,` with `\t` when displaying to `stdout` (second bullet option), the items are of arbitrary length, so don't line up in a nice format due to variances in tabs.

I have done quite a bit of research, and I believe that string format options could accomplish what I'm after. That said, I can't seem to find an example that helps me get the syntax correct.

I would prefer to **not use an external library**. I am aware that there are many options available if I went that route, but I want the script to be as compatible and simple as possible.

Here is an example:

```
value1,somevalue2,value3,reallylongvalue4,value5,superlongvalue6
value1,value2,reallylongvalue3,value4,value5,somevalue6
```

Can you help me please? Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

rows = list(csv.reader(StringIO(
    '''value1,somevalue2,value3,reallylongvalue4,value5,superlongvalue6
value1,value2,reallylongvalue3,value4,value5,somevalue6''')))

widths = [max(len(row[i]) for row in rows) for i in range(len(rows[0]))]

for row in rows:
    print(' | '.join(cell.ljust(width) for cell, width in zip(row, widths)))
```

Output:

```
value1 | somevalue2 | value3           | reallylongvalue4 | value5 | superlongvalue6
value1 | value2     | reallylongvalue3 | value4           | value5 | somevalue6
```

Comment: Excellent - I think this is going to work. Let's say I have a list named "results" instead of statically supplying "value1, somevalue2, etc." as in the example above.

Instead, I tried:
rows = list(csv.reader(StringIO(results)))


Can I not do this? It seems to jumble up the data and not insert any new lines.

Comment: The `list(csv.reader(StringIO(...` part is just to make a complete demo. If you already have a list of lists of strings, that is your `rows`.

Comment: Ah ok - I have a single list of CSV strings, but not a list of lists of strings - if that makes sense.

Comment: Indeed - that's what I tried. When doing so, I receive "IndexError: list index out of range." Looking back through the code now to ensure I didn't do something stupid, but "results" should be a regular Python list of strings, with each string being a CSV representation of the data.

Comment: Where do you receive that error? And are you sure that every row has the same number of cells?

Comment: I have a printData function, and to it I am passing "results" as a list. The code bombs when encountering the widths= statement (  widths = [max(len(row[i]) for row in rows) for i in range(len(rows[0]))] ). With regards to your question about the same number of cells, yes, but some fields are empty, and simply have a comma to serve as a placeholder for the empty data.

Comment: That was it -- I added a space to the empty fields ([space][comma]) and it worked perfectly. You're awesome. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printCsvStringListAsTable(csvStrings):

    # convert to list of lists
    csvStrings = map(lambda x: x.split(','), csvStrings)

    # get max column widths for printing
    widths = []
    for idx in range(len(csvStrings[0])):
        columns = map(lambda x: x[idx], csvStrings)
        widths.append(
            len(
                max(columns, key = len)
            )
        )

    # print the csv strings
    for row in csvStrings:
        cells = []
        for idx, col in enumerate(row):
            format = '%-' + str(widths[idx]) + "s"
            cells.append(format % (col))
        print ' |'.join(cells)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    printCsvStringListAsTable([
        'col1,col2,col3,col4',
        'val1,val2,val3,val4',
        'abadfafdm,afdafag,aadfag,aadfaf',
    ])
```

Output:

```
col1      |col2    |col3   |col4
val1      |val2    |val3   |val4
abadfafdm |afdafag |aadfag |aadfaf
```

The answer by Alex Hall is definitely better and a terse form of the same code which I have written.