# Aligning outputs of different lengths

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I recently saw a post on how to align outputs ([Python: Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment)). The problem about the answers on that page is that none of the responses answered my question. Yes, it taught me how to align single outputs but not outputs of a different length. This is an example code to show you what I mean:

```
purchasableItems = {'1234' : {'name' : 'tomato' : 'price' : 0.20}
                    '8765' : {'name' : 'mango' : 'price' : 1},
                    '5678' : {'name' : 'pineapple' : 'price' : 1}}
choice = input("Code: ") #write the items 4 digit code
amount = input("Amount: ") #how much of that item
price = int(amount) * (purchasableItems[choice]['price']
print("That would be {} {} {:>5} {:>5} {:>5}".format(choice, purchasableItems[choice]['name'], amount, purchasableItems[choice]['price'], price))
```

I have tried to re arrange the `'{:>5}'` into various other numbers but it didn't allow me to print into the way I wanted, I would like it to print out as:

```
Code: 1234
Amount: 3
That would be: 1234 tomato    3   0.20    0.60
Code: 8765
Amount: 2
That would be: 8765 mango     2   1.00    2.00
```

When the user is done I want the program to output a receipt:

```
Your receipt is:
1234 tomato   3   0.20   0.60
8765 mango    2   1.00   2.00
```

As you can see the receipt is aligned perfectly.

But it actually outputs as, depending on the length of the item

```
Your receipt is:
1234 tomato   3   0.20   0.60
5678 pineapple    2   1.00   2.00
```

For the love of anything I can't figure it out

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321732/python-print-list-of-csv-strings-in-aligned-columns/40321855#40321855

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but unfortunately that did not answer my question

Comment: What happens when you try to adapt the code there to your purposes?

Comment: It out puts in this  fashion: `Your receipt is:
1234 tomato   3   0.20   0.60
8765 mango    2   1.00   2.00' unaligned. The difference is much more clear to see in examples such as: `Your receipt is:
1234 tomato   3   0.20   0.60
8765 pineapple    2   1.00   2.00`

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't quite show up correctly in comments so I edited my post

Comment: I'm asking, what happens when you try to adapt the code in the answer that I linked to your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t` enter a tab break to line prints up. If it hasn't quite lined up you can have more than one. `\t\t`

I'm having trouble demonstrating this with your code as I am getting syntax errors. But here is an example from one of my scripts:

```
print ("Floating Value:\t" , value)
print ("Decimal Value:\t" , finalans)
```

This is output:

```
Floating Value:  010000111111101101
Decimal Value:   123.25
```

Another example with multiple `\t`s:

```
print ("Diameter = \t\t" , 2 * radius , "cm")
print ("Circumference = \t" , 2 * radius * pi , "cm")
print ("Area = \t\t\t" , pi * radius ** 2 , "cm")
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you give me an example

Comment: My apologies. I tried to get it to work with your code but having issues. See edit for an example from one of my programs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but unfortunately that method doesn't work