# How do I convert this output to a table

Tags: python

This is my output and my attempt at printing a formatted table, however it keeps giving the error "zero length field name in format".
How can I print the output as a formatted table without using modules and preferably this/similar method:

The names are made up for testing purposes:)

code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newOrder = [['gtin', 'name', 'price', 'quantity'], ['01234567', 'apples', '1.50', '12', ],
            ['01234566', 'applesxyz', '1.50', '12', ], ['01234565', 'asdasdapples', '1.50', '102', ],
            ['11234567', 'apples', '1.50', '12', ]]

widths = [max(len(row[i]) for row in newOrder) for i in range(len(newOrder[0]))]

for row in newOrder:
    print(' | '.join(cell.ljust(width) for cell, width in zip(row, widths)))
```

Output:

```
gtin     | name         | price | quantity
01234567 | apples       | 1.50  | 12      
01234566 | applesxyz    | 1.50  | 12      
01234565 | asdasdapples | 1.50  | 102     
11234567 | apples       | 1.50  | 12
```

This was based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321732/python-print-list-of-csv-strings-in-aligned-columns/40321855#40321855). I didn't want to mark it as a duplicate since this question doesn't involve CSVs.

Comment: thank you so much, this really helped because i could do it with modules but not without. Appreciated.